# Vue JS Component V-Model $emit

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using Vue JS 2 with Laravel 5.5. When I use a component and pass back the v-model within an $emit and then look to use the data on it's parent it returns 'undefined' in production. However if I use on my local dev environment it works fine?

The idea is that I can collect the data from the text editor and then store when saving the content.

I've tried "npm run development"

**My component**

```
<template>
    <div>
    <ckeditor 
      v-model="editorInfo.content" 
      :config="config" 
      @blur="onBlur($event)">
    </ckeditor>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Ckeditor from 'vue-ckeditor2';
    export default {
      components: { Ckeditor },
      props: {
        type: '',
        content: ''
      },
      data () {
        return {
          content: '',
          editorInfo: {
            type: '',
            content: this.content
          },
          config: {
            height: 300,
          }
        }
      },
      methods: {
        onBlur (editor) {
          this.editorInfo.type = this.type;
          this.$emit('update',this.editorInfo);
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

**My Parent**

```
import MyCkeditor from './../components/MyCkeditor';

new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  components: { MyCkeditor }, 
  data: {
    category: {
        title: '',
        description: '',
        extra_content: '',
    }
  }
  methods: {
    Update(value){
      console.log(value);
      if(value.type == 'description'){
        this.category.description = value.content;
      } else {
        this.category.extra_content = value.content;
      }
    }
  },
})
```

**My HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Description</label>
<my-ckeditor :type="'description'" v-on:update="Update"></my-ckeditor>
</div>
```

Comment: if its working locally then npm run production and then deploy it to the server

Comment: I've tried this but it was the same ?

Comment: is it the template that you have posted, that are you listening for the emit ?

Comment: I'm listening for the emit on the parent with v-on:update="Update" which then calls the method on the parent